# Run yarn/npm scripts from a subfolder's package.json

Tags: yarnpkg, npm-scripts

I maintain a [monorepo](https://github.com/react-querybuilder/react-querybuilder) for the [`react-querybuilder`](https://react-querybuilder.js.org/) package. I'm [merging](https://github.com/react-querybuilder/react-querybuilder/pull/370) in the [documentation website code](https://github.com/react-querybuilder/react-querybuilder.github.io) under the `/website` directory, but not as a workspace (those are in `/packages/*`).

The `/website` directory has its own `package.json` with the `docusaurus *` scripts (start/build/deploy/etc.). I'd like to have scripts in the root `/package.json` that execute the scripts in `/website/package.json`. Currently I have something like this in `/package.json`:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "website:install": "cd website && yarn",
    "website:start": "cd website && yarn start",
    "website:build": "cd website && yarn build",
    "website:deploy": "cd website && yarn deploy"
  }
}
```

Is there a better, more generic way to do that? This way I have to name every script twice, once in `/package.json` and once in `/website/package.json`.

(I tried `--cwd`, but that doesn't actually run scripts defined in that other directory's `package.json`. It runs the scripts defined in the *root* `package.json` *from* the other directory. E.g., `yarn --cwd website build` is effectively the same as `yarn build`, at least in my case.)

I thought there might be a `yarn` flag like `--cwd` (`--pkg`? `--config`?) that actually runs the scripts defined in the other directory, or maybe you'd have to specify a file.

Am I missing something?

Comment: The way I resolved/worked around this in my case was to add the `/website` directory to the `"workspaces"` list in package.json, but *not* add it to the `"packages"` list in lerna.json. That way it gets recognized by `yarn` but doesn't get published when I run `lerna publish`.